# Use of spanish babel in beamer

Tags: beamer, babel, accents

I downloaded a `beamer` template from http://cameron.bracken.bz/beamer-template/comment-page-1#comment-734 and I want to use it for a presentation in Spanish but when I try to use accents  it doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress,utf8]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\section{\scshape Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\title{Identificacion}
%\subtitle{SUBTITLE}
\author{
Cameron Bracken\\
{\it Humboldt State University}\\
}
\date{
\today
}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{\scshape Background}
 \subsection{frame 1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item atención
\item Item B
\begin{itemize}
\item Subitem 1
\item Subtem 2
\end{itemize}
\item Item C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This example compiles perfectly but when I change `\title{Identificacion}` for `\title{Identificación}` it crashes. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Remove the `utf8` option and add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Wellcome to tex.stackexchange! What system/OS? You should follow @egreg's recommendation and add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. However, even with `utf8` it ran correctly on my TeXLive under Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I use Mac OS 10.6.8...I use Latexian 1.2.4 and I have two documents with the same code, I followed @egreg's recommendation and one of them compiles and the other one doesn't and I don't know why. I'm just gonna keep the one that does and hope it keeps working. Thanks!!!

Comment: Sometimes you need to delete *.aux files after babel changes.

Comment: 'Works for me' too

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem which cannot be reproduced.
